# Iphone AppStore approval time company vs. individual

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I'm getting ready to submit my first iOS to the app store. I'm currently weighing the pros and cons of creating an LLC for my developer account to submit to the app store, as opposed to just submitting as an individual.

In previous forum posts, it seems Apple used to take much longer (months) to approve an app from a company, whereas for individuals it can take less than a week.

Has this changed at all or is this how it continues to be?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming; it's about company legal structure and Apple approval policy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter to be honest. There is not much difference between Individual and Company account to start with. There are only team organization and such feature available to Company which are not available to individual developers. Personally I haven't seen any issues as far as submissions are concerned. However, if you are thinking of switching your individual account to company, you'll have to submit your DUNS registration number which might take time(both getting one and then submitting to apple and upgrading your account). This however doesn't affect app submission and app approval time. If there is something wrong with the app, they'll reach out to you and that might take time(not so long as months though).

Hope this helps. All the best!